# PGF of indepedent random integers

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Backrground**

The PGF of a random integer $N$ with probability distribution $p_N(n)\triangleq \mathbb{P}(N=n)$ is defined as
\begin{equation*}
G_N(s)\triangleq \mathbb{E}[s^N]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n\,p_N(n)
\end{equation*}
for any $s\in\mathbb{C}$ such that the series converge (trivially, a sufficient condition is $s\in[0,1]$).

Now assume that $N=N_1+N_2$ with $N_1,N_2$ independent and distributed according to $p_{N_1}(n), p_{N_2}(n)$. It is well-known that in this case the PGF of $N$ is given by the simple factorization
\begin{equation*}
G_N(s)=G_{N_1}(s)\,G_{N_2}(s)
\end{equation*}
in my opinion the simplest way to prove this formula is by computing the expectation of $s^N$ over the joint space of $N_1,N_2$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
G_{N}(s)\triangleq \mathbb{E}[s^N]=\mathbb{E}[s^{N_1+N_2}]&=\sum_{n_1,n_2=0}^\infty \underbrace{s^{n_1+n_2}}_{=s^{n_1}s^{n_2}}\,\underbrace{p_{N_1,N_2}(n_1,n_2)}_{=p_{N_1}(n_1)\,p_{N_2}(n_2)}\\
&=\sum_{n_1,n_2=0}^\infty s^{n_1} p_{N_1}(n_1)\,s^{n_2} p_{N_2}(n_2)\\
&=\underbrace{\left(\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty s^{n_1}\,p_{N_1}(n_1)\right)}_{\triangleq G_{N_1}(s)}
\underbrace{\left(\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty s^{n_2}\,p_{N_2}(n_2)\right)}_{\triangleq G_{N_2}(s)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I'm using the short notation $\sum_{a,b=0}^\infty \triangleq \sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{b=0}^\infty$.

**The problem**

Since $N=N_1+N_2$ and $N_1,N_2$ are independent, we know that the distribution $N$ is given by the convolution between $p_{N_1}(n)$ and $p_{N_2}(n)$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
p_N(n)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_{N_1}(i)\,p_{N_2}(n-i)
\end{equation*}
thus we can compute the PGF of $N$ as
\begin{equation*}
G_N(s)\triangleq \mathbb{E}[s^N]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_{N_1}(i)\,p_{N_2}(n-i)\right)
\end{equation*}
so, it must be a way to rearrange this expression so that we get the previous factorization.
In order to do that, I start by noting
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
G_N(s)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_{N_1}(i)\,p_{N_2}(n-i)\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^i\,s^{n-i} \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_{N_1}(i)\,p_{N_2}(n-i)\right)\\
&=\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty s^i\,p_{N_1}(i)\right)}_{\triangleq F_1(s)}\underbrace {\left(\sum_{n,j=0}^\infty s^{n-j}\,p_{N_2}(n-j)\right)}_{\triangleq F_2(s)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
the first factor $F_1(s)$ is clearly the PGF of $N_1$, i.e. $F_1(s)=G_{N_1}(s)$. The problem is for the second factor $F_2(s)$, is it correct to say that it is the PGF of $N_2$, i.e. $F_2(s)=G_{N_2}(s)$?
I'm not fully convinced that $F_2(s)=G_{N_2}(s)$ and I would like to have an hand to understand how to prove $F_2(s)=G_{N_2}(s)$, i.e. how to prove
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n,j=0}^\infty s^{n-j}\,p_{N_2}(n-j) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty s^k\,p_{N_2}(k)
\end{equation*}

Comment: The second line of your equation is not correct. You cannot use the summation index $i$ outside of the scope of the corresponding summation $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $N_1$ and $N_2$ takes non-negative integer values only, here is a way to go: First we write

\begin{align*}
G_N(s)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s^n \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} p_{N_1}(i)\,p_{N_2}(n-i)\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} s^i p_{N_1}(i) \cdot s^{n-i}p_{N_2}(n-i).
\end{align*}

Now we consider the parametrization $(a, b) = (i, n-i)$. Note that this is a bijection between the two set $A = \{(n, i) : n \geq 0 \text{ and } 0 \leq i \leq n\}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2 = \{(a, b) : a, b \geq 0\}$. Hence by Fubini's theorem, for $|s| < 1$ we can rearrange the order of summation to write

\begin{align*}
G_N(s)
&=\sum_{(n,i) \in A} s^i p_{N_1}(i) \cdot s^{n-i}p_{N_2}(n-i) \\
&=\sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2} s^a p_{N_1}(a) \cdot s^{b}p_{N_2}(b) \\
&=\sum_{a=0}^{\infty} \sum_{b=0}^{\infty} s^a p_{N_1}(a) \cdot s^{b}p_{N_2}(b) \\
&= G_{N_1}(s) G_{N_2}(s).
\end{align*}

(If both sides define analytic functions on a larger domain $\mathcal{D}$, then the principle of analytic continuation guarantees that the equality continues to hold on $\mathcal{D}$.)